# Cant add gui elements from other methods and if statmens

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

Hey all I have one  question I am new to GUI stuff so I need some help when I want to add an element to a window using some other method or if statement I don't get error but it doesn't show up hears a code I marked problem  I am working in java by the way this is not whole program but only this is a problem

```
import java.awt.*;  

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

private JTextField usernameTF;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private String username,password;
private JRadioButton A,B,C,D,F;

//private JComboBox box;
private JLabel logo,errorPic,promt;
private JButton logIn;
private boolean value;
private Apples function= new Apples();

public Gui(){
    super ("Awsome Progrma");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Icon errorIcon = new  ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("wrong.png"));
    errorPic = new JLabel(errorIcon);

    usernameTF = new JTextField(10);
    usernameTF.setToolTipText("Enter your user name hear");
    add(usernameTF);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
    passwordField.setToolTipText("Enter your password hear");
    add(passwordField);

    logIn = new JButton("Log IN");
    add(logIn);

    usernameTF.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    username = event.getActionCommand();
                    password = passwordField.getText();
                    value = function.chack(username,password);
                    if (value == true){add(errorPic);}                      // this is a problem JLabel dosn't show up in my window 
                }
            }
        );
    passwordField.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    username = usernameTF.getText();;
                    password = event.getActionCommand();
                    value = function.chack(username,password);
                    if (value == true){add(errorPic);}                          // this is a problem JLabel dosn't show up in my window 
                }
            }
        );
    logIn.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    username = usernameTF.getText();
                    password = passwordField.getText();
                    value = function.chack(username,password);
                    if (value == true){add(errorPic);}                                  // this is a problem JLabel dosn't show up in my window 
                    }
                }
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW, you should use `.getPassword()` for passwords. `.getText()` is deprecated.

Comment: Have you debugged your application to check if the statement actually its true?

Comment: Yes i chacked it returns true

Answer (score 2):

The only GUI element that won't show up is the `Jlabel` `errorPic`. This is because the container needs to be validated after the component has been added. You need to call:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

after adding the `JLabel`. A better approach would be to add a `JLabel` with no image when adding components to the `JFrame` and later simply call `JLabel.setIcon` to update the label.

---

*Some side notes:*

- Don't extend `JFrame`. Instead create an instance of the window component directly.
- `JPassword.getText` is *deprecated*. Safer to use `JPassword.getPassword` instead.
- Consider using [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) at application startup.